# Loading SignalR with partial view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views, signalr

I've recently followed this link http://www.kevgriffin.com/why-should-asp-net-developers-consider-signalr-for-all-projects/ to get up and started with SignalR on ASP.NET MVC3.

What I want to do is to provide a partial view with SignalR capability. Hence, when I use AJAX to load the partial view, I call the following function on success:

```
function loadSuccess() {
    var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
    chat.writeMessage = function (msg) {
        $("#messages").append("<li>" + msg + "</li>");
    }

    $("#buttonSubmit").click(function () {
        chat.broadcastMessage($("#txtInput").val());
    });

    $.connection.hub.start();
}
```

The troublesome thing is that it does not seem to run (inserting an `alert('hi')` just after `var chat = ...` does not cause a dialog to show up after loading the partial view). However, if I run this piece of JavaScript once the entire DOM of the containing view is loaded (i.e., the partial view has not been loaded), the script runs perfectly fine.

Does anybody have any idea why I'm bumping into this problem?

**EDIT**: Sure, this is how I call loadSuccess...

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("chat", "Index", "Chat", ChatOpts)
```

...and the corresponding `ChatOpts`:

```
AjaxOptions ChatOpts = new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "placeholder",
    OnSuccess = "loadSuccess"
};
```

Comment: Can you post how do you call `loadSuccess`?

Comment: What if you insert an `alert` just before the `var chat = ...` line? Does it get executed? Are there errors in your javascript console? Is the AJAX request sent successfully? Can you see the partial contents refreshed when you click on the link?

Comment: If I insert an `alert` just before, it runs perfectly fine. I get the following error in my JS console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'chatHub' of undefined`

Comment: Take a look at your browser tools and look for errors (in the network tab as well as the console). Then head to the FAQ on the wiki https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki to find more specific help.

Comment: Do you have the script reference to SignalR ? If so, where? Without this there will be no Signalr javascript on the page to call. E.g. <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-0.5.2.js"></script>